# How can my company logo appear on other people's phones when I call them or they call me?

Tags: contacts

When I have called some companies their logo or photo automatically appears on my phone as a contact. How can I do the same?

Comment: Are you using the new Kitkat dialler that uses Google Search?

Comment: @RossC The body of the questions are actually opposites: Incoming vs Outgoing call. Although the title of this question was sufficient for both cases.

Comment: Yeah I saw that, but it's really just how can I have a logo in the Dialler, without any further specifics to answer the thing. @JRacoon

Answer (score 1):

Install [Truecaller](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.truecaller) and add your contact image.

Alternatively, fill up your Google or Facebook profile with images. The Google Dialer/Contact software will pick up the image you had provided in your accounts.

Comment: If I use Truecaller, looks like the logo is shown to Truecaller users only? Or is there any setting that I miss?